# CatBoostError: cat_features must be integer or string, real number values and NaN values should be converted to string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with 122 columns which looks like:

```
train.head()

SK_ID_CURR  TARGET  NAME_CONTRACT_TYPE  CODE_GENDER FLAG_OWN_CAR    FLAG_OWN_REALTY CNT_CHILDREN    AMT_INCOME_TOTAL    AMT_CREDIT  AMT_ANNUITY ... FLAG_DOCUMENT_18    FLAG_DOCUMENT_19    FLAG_DOCUMENT_20    FLAG_DOCUMENT_21    AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_HOUR  AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_DAY   AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_WEEK  AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_MON   AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_QRT   AMT_REQ_CREDIT_BUREAU_YEAR
0   100002  1   Cash loans  M   N   Y   0   202500.0    406597.5    24700.5 ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   100003  0   Cash loans  F   N   N   0   270000.0    1293502.5   35698.5 ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   100004  0   Revolving loans M   Y   Y   0   67500.0 135000.0    6750.0  ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   100006  0   Cash loans  F   N   Y   0   135000.0    312682.5    29686.5 ... 0   0   0   0   255 255 255 255 65535   255
4   100007  0   Cash loans  M   N   Y   0   121500.0
```

I've imputed all NaNs and wanna use CatBoost now as follows:

```
# Get variables for a model
x = train.drop(["TARGET"], axis=1)
y = train["TARGET"]

#Do train data splitting
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

cat_features = np.where(x.dtypes != float)[0]

cat = CatBoostClassifier(one_hot_max_size=7, iterations=21, random_seed=42, use_best_model=True, eval_metric='Accuracy', loss_function='Logloss')

cat.fit(X_train, y_train, cat_features = cat_features, eval_set=(X_test, y_test))
pred = cat.predict(X_test)

pool = Pool(X_train, y_train, cat_features=cat_features)
cv_scores = cv(pool, cat.get_params(), fold_count=10, plot=True)
print('CV score: {:.5f}'.format(cv_scores['test-Accuracy-mean'].values[-1]))
print('The test accuracy is :{:.6f}'.format(accuracy_score(y_test, cat.predict(X_test))))
```

which raises:

> CatBoostError: Invalid type for cat_feature[534,6]=118975.5 :
>   cat_features must be integer or string, real number values and NaN
>   values should be converted to string.

`NaN`s all are imputed as mentioned (checked) and in the code is stated that `cat_features` are other than real numbers.

Would someone help me to solve the mystery, please?

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to use a column with `dtype` `float` for categorical column. To fix the error convert it to an `int`;

```
train["a"] = train["a"].astype(np.int)
```

however, in your case 118975.5 doesn't look like a valid category, so you might want to double check if you want to use that column as categorical.

Here is small example that reproduces the error and fix:

```
from catboost import CatBoostRegressor
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

train_data = [[1, 4],
              [4.0, 5]]

train = pd.DataFrame(train_data, columns=["a", "b"])

# train["a"] = train["a"].astype(np.int) # This line fixes Invalid type for cat_feature issue

train_labels = [10, 20]
model = CatBoostRegressor(iterations=2,
                          cat_features=["a"]
                          )
model.fit(train, train_labels)
```

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't exactly a solution, but I figure that 'cat_feature[534,6]=118975.5' tell you that there is some problem on the 7th column.

I'm facing a similar problem now.

Comment: I figure out the problem in my case. For anyone that is curious, I'm getting the error because I'm using FeatureUnion for combining categorical and numerical features, When I concat, the original feature index changed. Whereas I set the catboost to take the original categorical feature index, thus the error.

Comment: You were correct. Looks like a bug in CatBoost.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your feature names order on your model `cat.feature_names_`.
For the safe way is

```py
cat.predict(X_test[cat.feature_names_])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your data has missing values and you had not imputed them. That is the possible reason based on my experience. You can .fillna(-999, inplace=Ture) for all your features. Thereafter, these error messages would disappear.
You may doubt the imputation. Do not worry about it. Catboost will classify these missing values filled with -999 into a category. When you have done this and get your result, you need to go back to inspect the reasonability.

Hope this would be helpful.